# Difference between response.send and response.write in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I have written a small API which uses the Node js "restify" framework. This API receives a request (actually anything after "/") and then send that request to another server. Get the response back from server and passes the response back to original source of request. For this API I am using both restify server and client.

Below is that API code for better understanding.

```
var apiServer = require('apiServer');
apiServer.start();

var restify = require('restify');
var assert = require('assert');

function onRequest(request, response, next)
{
    var client = restify.createStringClient({ 
        url: 'http://example.com'
    });

    client.get('/' + request.params[0], function(err, req, res, data) {
        assert.ifError(err);

        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        response.writeHead(res.statusCode);
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
    next();
}

function start()
{
    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.get(/^\/(.*)/, onRequest);
    server.listen(8888);

    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Now I need to know the difference between `response.write` and `response.send` of Node.js. Because with `response.write` I can set header and write in it but it is not possible to do anything with headers when I use `response.send`. When I use `response.send` with `setHeader()` or `writeHeader()` I get this error:

```
http.js:691
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
          ^
    Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

There is also another thing. With `response.send()` I get the complete HTML output on the screen like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n\t<head></head></html> ..... "bla bla bla"
```

But with `response.write` I do not get the html on screen but only the text `"bla bla bla"`.

It would be great if someone can explain me the differences.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I can't find `response.send()` in the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), but I assume `.send()` will fill in and send the response so can only be called once, whereas `.write()` will just write the response, but you have to send it using `response.end()`

This means you can edit the headers using `.write()` because the response has not been sent yet.

**EDIT** :

`response.send()` is part of the [restify Response API wrapper](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Response-API)

Comment: But what about the types of out that I received with those two functions? Like I said, res.write does not print the entire html on screen or browser but res.send does.

Comment: @user3275959 and also could you explain the differences in output a bit more?

Comment: res.send() is a deprecated method. see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550049/node-express-errror-express-deprecated-res-sendstatus-use-res-sendstatusst

Answer (score 68):

`response.send(msg)` is equal to `response.write(msg);response.end();`

Which means, `send` can only be called once, `write` can be called many times, but you must call `end` yourself.

Comment: But what about the types of out that I received with those two functions? Like I said, res.write does not print the entire html on screen or browser but res.send does.

Comment: You want to display html code in browser? If so, just add head content-type, like `response.writeHead('content-type','text/plain')`

Comment: Basically, `response.send(msg)` is the same as `response.end(msg)`. You just have to type an extra s.

Comment: @minseong This is not entirely true. Consider `response.write("Hello");response.end(" World")` vs `response.write("Hello");response.send(" World")`. The later would give me an error saying "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." Not sure what is going on.

Comment: @Kun Look at the structure of an HTTP request -- by the time you've started sending the body of the request ("Hello") you _have_ to have sent the headers already. `send` attempts to guess and set headers based on the type of the object you pass it, so it fails if the headers are already locked.

Comment: @NicHartley Ah, I see

Answer (score 31):

`res.send()` is part of **Express.js** instead of pure **Node.js**.

Just an side observation. My app sometimes send back a very large **Json** object ( **HighChart** object that contains over 100k points). With `res.send()` sometimes it hangs and choke up the server, whereas `res.write()` and `res.end()` handle it just fine.

I also noticed a memory spike when `res.send()` is invoked.

Comment: This is key! res.send is only in Express note Node. It also performs a bunch of magic like setting content-length and content-type. If you want to have absolute control, you need res.write and res.end. In fact the express compress module at this point only runs with res.write & res.end.

Comment: Woops disregard the whole not working in Express: https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/39

Comment: working opposite at my end, res.send(json) is helping me to return a large json very fine whereas res.write(json) with res.end() doesn't do the job

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to send huge text data(295mb) over http using res.send(data) and res.write(data). I noticed that res.send(data) is slower than res.write(data). I observed following things.

**res.send(data):** it can be called only once and it sends data in chunk of some buffer size to client and then again comes back and sends another chunk of buffer size so there is a lot of back and forth http communication.

**res.write(data):** It can be called multiple times followed by res.end() and It creates buffer size based on whole data and sends over http so it would be faster in case of huge amount of data.