# node-express error : express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

I am trying to send an integer via `response.send()` but I keep getting this error

> express deprecated res.send(status): Use res.sendStatus(status) instead

I am not sending a Status, my code is

```
app.get('/runSyncTest' , function(request, response){  

var nodes = request.query.nodes;
var edges = request.query.edges;
if (edges == "" ){
    edges = []
}

userStory.userStory(nodes,edges);
connection.query('SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM report ', function(err,results, fields) {
                idTest = results[0].id
                response.send (idTest)
});

});
```

Comment: just to avoid warning, how about returning JSON like `response.send ({max:idTest})`

Comment: Regarding `res.send()`, [the fine manual](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send) states: _"The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array."_. So integers aren't directly supported and need to be converted to one of those types first.

Comment: the JSON trick worked thank you @HarisHasan

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You could try this:

```js
res.status(200).send((results[0].id).toString());
```

Guys are right - it doesn't allow numbers.
Prooflink: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

Comment: thanks it help ,my problem is trying to send extra content which are not string

Comment: @letie but I also do not remember what I was asking at that time, 2 years back...

Answer (score 25):

This is because you are sending numeric value in the res.send.

You could send a json object or convert it to string.

Answer (score 7):

(as mentioned in the comments already)

[The manual states](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send):

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, or an Array.

So integers aren't directly supported and need to be converted to one of those types first. For instance:

```
response.send(String(idTest));
```

Answer (score 6):

**Its Deprecated, Express 5 No Longer Supports The Signature Like** -

```
res.json(200, {
   result: result
});
```

Instead, use a below method, Means you only need to change the format of sending responses.

```
res.status(statusCode).json(result);
```

**Example** -

```
res.status(200).json({'success' : true, 'result': result})
```

Answer (score 5):

As long as you're not sending String or Object/Array data you get an error.
Solution convert your data to string:

```
app.get('/runSyncTest', function(req, res) {
    var number = 5000;
    res.send((number).toString()); //Number is converted with toString()
});
```

Comment: This answer works without any error or warning. Clearly, this is a bug in the error handling of Express. it has a type error but showed the wrong error (deprecated...)

Comment: @MiladAbooali if you are using JS, there're no type checks by default in JS, thus TS was introduced.

Comment: ,Thanks for reminding that. but I'm not talking about type checks. I meant from a bug is the wrong error message. This is about the Express send method, not JS  basics. We expect to see anything like empty input or wrong input but not a deprecated notice! This msg is not related to the error at all

Answer (score 3):

Use like this,

```
res.status(404).send('Page Not found');
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue at all; you are literally just sending an error in response

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a deprecated warning in node-express typescript project due to `res.send(403);`

Solution 1 -

```
res.sendStatus(403);
```

Solution 2 -

```
res.status(403).json(
        {
            'success': false,
            'result': 'forbidden'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have in your code:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

then you should always return a 'JSON' with the response, for example:

the wrong answer for get request is:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const result = 3;
    res.send(result);
});
```

the right answer should be:

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const result = 3;
    res.send({ result });
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply converting it to a string works great.

`response.send(idTest.toString()`

Comment: This is already covered in previous answers

Comment: And it's also missing a ')'