# mongoose findByIdUpdate is deprecated

Tags: mongoose, deprecated

I tried to use this method in mongoose, `Model.findByIdAndUpdate()`, but the console shows it as deprecated.

I know that's a disable warning.

My question is, what is the correct method to make this petition?

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(data.id,{$set:user},{new: true},(errUpdate, result)=>{
            if(errUpdate){
                console.log("error",errUpdate);
            }
            if(data){
                console.log("result", result);

            }
        })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate successfully updates document but ruturns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198856/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-successfully-updates-document-but-ruturns-error)

Answer (score 0):

did you tried mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()`

The `findOneAndUpdate()` function in Mongoose has a wide variety of use cases. You should use `save()` to update documents where possible, but there are some cases where you need to use `findOneAndUpdate()`

Read more at  [How to Use findOneAndUpdate() in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html)

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(data.id,{$set:user},{new: true},(errUpdate, result)=>{
            if(errUpdate){
                console.log("error",errUpdate);
            }
            if(data){
                console.log("result", result);

            }
        })
```