# How to handle response from Express response.write() in Angular $http

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to upload a csv file using [ng-file-upoad](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload). Here is my code snippet:

```
Upload.upload({
   url: baseUrl + '/file-upload',
   data: {
      file: file
   }
 })
 .then(function(res) {
    console.log('success: ===> ', res);
 }, function(err) {
    console.log('erroir: ===> ', err);
 }, function() {
    console.log('progress: ', arguments);
 });
```

And in node environment I'm parsing the file and inserting the data in database. I don't want to close the connection. That's why I used "response.write". Here is my code snippet:

```
var path = req.files.file.path,
    currentIndex = 0;

fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) { 
    if(err) {
         // handle error
    } else {
        // making array (dataArray) from data
        dataArray.forEach(function(eachData){
            newEntry = new app.db.models.SomeCollection(eachData);
            newEntry.save(function(err, data) {
              if (currentIndex === dataArray.length) {
                 res.end('DONE!');
              } else {
                  currentIndex++;
                  res.write(JSON.stringify({
                     total: dataArray.length,
                     done: currentIndex
                  }));
              }
            });
        })
    }
});
```

My question is how I will get the data I'm passing in "res.write"? I don't want to use socket for only this purpose. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to close the connection"?

Comment: I don't want to use response.send or response.end. Actually the file contains 5000 data, and I want to show a progress bar depends on the response from server. Is there any way to send data from server except socket?

Comment: The connection made by ajax requests will close once you send the response back. Otherwise you've to use socket connection. *"I don't want to use socket for only this purpose"* - what else is the purpose of socket connection..? Your only closest option will be to implement long polling

Comment: You can't do it with a single `http` request. Or you should create a socket and pipe a stream there, or you should make many `http` requests from the client to the server.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm facing the same problem right now. Have you found the answer since then?

Answer (score 1):

As already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749590/difference-between-response-send-and-response-write-in-node-js#answer-21749726):

> response.send(msg) is equal to response.write(msg);response.end();
>
> Which means, send can only be called once, write can be called many times, but you must call end yourself.

You are probably not receiving the response because `response.end()` is missing.

Once you `end()` your response you should be able to access the response data in your angular controller in the Upload.upload promise that is returned.

It's not like *close a connection* as you said. This is not a *socket-ish* like implementation (such as `ws` or `socket.io`). Once a request is made it should have a response even if it is to provide error details about that request (i.e. status 401, 403, 404, etc).

Comment: I've checked that link. But I don't want to use response.send or response.end. Actually the file contains 5000 data, and I want to show a progress bar depends on the response from server. Is there any way to send data from server?

Comment: Take a look at this blog: http://www.jonahnisenson.com/file-uploads-using-angular-and-nodeexpress/. It is explained how to implement progress during file upload in angular. It is implemented client side not server side.

Comment: I'm not talking about file upload progress. Please read the question properly. I'm working with the data after the file upload is done. I want to show the progress of inserted data, not the upload percentage of the file.

Answer (score 0):

in your angular component:

```
  ...
  constructor(private incrementalService: IncrementalService) {}
   
  incrementalTest() { //activate with a button or whatnot
    this.incrementalService.increment().subscribe( (result:any) => {
      if (result.partialText) {
        console.log(partialText); //do whatever you need to do with your partial results here!
      }
    })
  }
```

your angular service:

```
   import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
   public class IncrementalService {

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

     increment(): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
        const options = {
          reportProgress: true,
          responseType: 'text',
          observe: 'events'
        }
        return this.http.request('get', 'http://someURL', { ...this.addRawHeaderOptions(), ...options});
     }

     private addRawHeaderOptions() {
        const authHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          //authorization, Cache-Control: 'no-cache, Pragma:'no-cache', et al.     }
        return { headers: authHeaders }
     }
   }
```

Finally, your back-end service (this is express, but should work similarly for raw node):

```
  async function(request, response) {
    const increments = [ 1,2,3,4 ];
    response.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    for (const value of increments) { //contains async call - not switch-outable for a forEach.
      response.write(`increment - ${value} `);
      const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      await delay(1000)
    }
    response.status(200).end()
  }
```

browser console output when run:

- increment - 1
- increment - 1 increment - 2
- increment - 1 increment - 2 increment - 3
- increment - 1 increment - 2 increment - 3 increment - 4

!!Sorry for any typos - i had to transcribe this from a locked-down machine.