# What is the difference between res.send and res.write in express?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, response, send

I am a beginner to `express.js` and I am trying to understand the difference between `res.send` & `res.write` ?

Comment: refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749590/difference-between-response-send-and-response-write-in-node-js

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**`res.send`**

- `res.send` is only in Express.js.
- Performs many useful tasks for simple non-streaming responses.
- Ability to automatically assigns the `Content-Length` HTTP response header field.
- Ability to provides automatic HEAD & HTTP cache freshness support.
- *Practical explanation*

  - `res.send` can only be called once, since it is equivalent to `res.write` + `res.end()`
  - Example:

    ```js
    app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
        res.send('OK');
    });
    ```

For more details:

- [Express.js: Response](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res)

---

**`res.write`**

- Can be called multiple times to provide successive parts of the body.
- Example:

  ```js
  response.write('<html>');
  response.write('<body>');
  response.write('<h1>Hello, World!</h1>');
  response.write('</body>');
  response.write('</html>');
  response.end();
  ```

For more details:

- [response.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)
- [Anatomy of an HTTP Transaction: Sending Response Body](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#sending-response-body)

Comment: To clarify on `res.write` little bit more, this is a method provided by `OutgoingMessage` class from node `http` module. Express.js `response` class inherits `OutgoingMessage` class. Below is the definition of `write` method:

```OutgoingMessage.prototype.write = function write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
  return write_(this, chunk, encoding, callback, false);
};
```

Comment: Another difference is, `send` automatically sets encoding to UTF-8

Comment: which has better performance, would write result in better first paint timing?

Answer (score 17):

`res.send` is equivalent to `res.write + res.end`
So the key difference is `res.send` can  be called only once where as `res.write` can be called multiple times followed by a `res.end`.

But apart from that `res.send` is part of Express. It can automatically detect the length  of response header.
But there may be be a chance of memory spike with res.send(), in case of large files, our application hangs in between .

Answer (score 11):

**One of the most important differences** not indicated in any of the answers are "draining".

The `res.write` may return true or false. As of the documentation:

> Returns true if the entire data was flushed successfully to the kernel
>   buffer. Returns false if all or part of the data was queued in user
>   memory. 'drain' will be emitted when the buffer is free again.

So, when doing `res.write`, the caller should hold off writing until the drain event emits if the `res.write` returned false.

All these are handled automatically in `res.send`. The trade off is the buffering you will have to do when using the latter.

Comment: Could we have some reference links about this please?

Comment: Express documentation has it all: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Answer (score 2):

I am also a beginner in this. But what I observed is that, if you write only `res.write()` the page will be loading continuously until you write `res.end()`. Whereas if you write `res.send()` there is no need of `res.end()`. `res.send()` basically it does both `res.write()` and `res.end()`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two line that needs to be shown up and you use res.send as

```
res.send("shows only First Line")
res.send("won't show second Line")
```

Then only first line will show up, whereas using `res.write` you have flexibility to write multiple line such as

```
res.write("Shows first line")
res.write("Shows second line")
res.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.send()` is equivalent to `res.write()+ res.end()`.
basically, `res.send` is for express and `res.write+res.end()` is for bare metal node ways to send data.