# Getting Can't set headers after they are sent after res.send() in express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting this error every time a do a `POST` request.
My code is:

```
records.post('/addNewRecord',
[
    check('applicant_name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant name cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_type').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Please select an applicant type').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_address').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant address cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_contact').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant contact cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building name cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_address').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building Address cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_area').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building Area cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('file_number').not().isEmpty().withMessage('File number cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('remark').trim().escape()
],
function(req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        res.status(200).send({message: errors.array(), saved : false})
    }
    const fileRecordData = {
        "APPLICANT_NAME": req.body.applicant_name,
        "APPLICANT_TYPE": req.body.applicant_type,
        "APPLICANT_ADDRESS": req.body.applicant_address,
        "APPLICANT_CONTACT": req.body.applicant_contact,
        "BUILDING_NAME": req.body.building_name,
        "BUILDING_ADDRESS": req.body.building_address,
        "BUILDING_AREA": req.body.building_area,
        "FILE_NUMBER": req.body.file_number,
        "REMARK": req.body.remark,
    }
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO ${process.env.FILE_RECORD_TBL} SET ?`, fileRecordData, function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(200).send({message : err, saved : false})
        }
        res.status(200).send({message : 'Record saved successfully', saved : true})
    })
}
```

)

I get this error every time irrespective of which res.status() gets called depending on the condition.

**I have seen other answers on SO but and I have applied them but the problem doesn't seem to go away.**

Comment: can you post the full route? maybe other code is sending something first. post the app js(atleast the relevant part)

Comment: @AritraChakraborty updated the question with full route please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending response two times that's why getting this error.

> And as per this code base you are getting error that's why your error block is calling with outer response

Try this:

```
    records.post('/addNewRecord', [
    check('applicant_name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant name cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_type').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Please select an applicant type').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_address').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant address cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('applicant_contact').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Applicant contact cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_name').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building name cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_address').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building Address cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('building_area').not().isEmpty().withMessage('Building Area cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('file_number').not().isEmpty().withMessage('File number cannot be empty').trim().escape(),
    check('remark').trim().escape()
  ],
  function (req, res) {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        // break the function execution if condition is true
     return  res.status(200).send({
        message: errors.array(),
        saved: false
      });
    }
    const fileRecordData = {
      "APPLICANT_NAME": req.body.applicant_name,
      "APPLICANT_TYPE": req.body.applicant_type,
      "APPLICANT_ADDRESS": req.body.applicant_address,
      "APPLICANT_CONTACT": req.body.applicant_contact,
      "BUILDING_NAME": req.body.building_name,
      "BUILDING_ADDRESS": req.body.building_address,
      "BUILDING_AREA": req.body.building_area,
      "FILE_NUMBER": req.body.file_number,
      "REMARK": req.body.remark,
    }
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO ${process.env.FILE_RECORD_TBL} SET ?`, fileRecordData, function (err, results, fields) {
      if (err) {
          // break the callback execution if getting error
        return res.status(200).send({
          message: err,
          saved: false
        })
      }
      res.status(200).send({
        message: 'Record saved successfully',
        saved: true
      });
    })
  });
```

Comment: this works with return but is using return mandatory with res.send() ??

Comment: how of handle it properly?....the first part of your answer doesn't work for me either

Comment: the main purpose is that it should not send response more than one times, and now its up to you how you want to handle

Comment: you mean even if they are in if-else block they should be send only once in a route?........can you show me how to do it without return

Comment: I have updated the answer and it should work in all scenario, BTW you need to take care the control flow of execution

Comment: thanks.... "take care of the control flow of execution" what do you mean by this can you please ellaborate

Comment: mean you need to understand the control flow where use `if else` where use `return` etc.. then you'll never stuck in such type of error

Comment: should I use res.write() and then a final res.end() in the end to do this without return

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692048/what-is-the-difference-between-res-send-and-res-write-in-express hope you'll get your answer