# Using res.write before res.send results in error

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I'm trying to understand why the following code throws an error.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.write("Hello");
    res.send(" World!");
})
// Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.write("Hello");
    res.write(" World!");
    res.end();
})
// Works fine
```

I don't see how headers are set after res.send since res.send is the one who sets the headers.

I read online that res.send is the equivalent of res.write + res.end, but this shows it is not entirely true.

I would like to be able to write base data to the response and then use res.send for it's useful task like automatically setting the Content-Type header based on the data sent.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.write("Base data");
    next();
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("Route specific data");
})
// Result: Base data + Route specific data
```

Is there something other than res.write which lets me write data to the response but doesn't conflict with res.send ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between res.send and res.write in express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692048/what-is-the-difference-between-res-send-and-res-write-in-express)

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send    The docs explicitly tell you this -> `This method performs many useful tasks for simple non-streaming responses:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`res.write` starts writing the body, but before it can do so, it must write all headers, and you cannot write any additional headers afterwards. But `res.send` writes an additional `Content-Type` header, based on whether its argument is a Javascript object or a a string. Therefore you cannot use `res.send` after `res.write`.

`res.send` is meant to be used on its own, like `res.json` or `res.render`.

Comment: Reading from the docs, I thought I couldn't change headers after res.end, but it really is after writing to the body. Thanks