# didn't get response when using res.write() inside of the fetch function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, fetch-api

I am using this <res.write()> ==> https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#responsewritechunk-encoding-callback (in nodejs)
and using this fetch ==> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

My situation is that I didn't see any response when using the res.write() function inside of the fetch function. for example, in the below backend code, I tried to put `res.write("456")` inside of the first then function below fetch, but I only see **123** returned in the frontend, no **456**.

```
res.write("123");
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then((response) => {response.json(), res.write("456")})
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

I have searched Google for a while, but didn't see anything related. My guess is that this could be because of async usage.
appreciate if someone can give suggestions.

===== **update** =====

res is express's res obj

```
async sendText(res: Response){
    res.write("123")
    fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
        .then((response) => {return response.json()})
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            res.write('456');
            res.end();
        });

}
```

seeing behavior: only see 123 in the frontend.

***VS***

```
async sendText(res: Response){
    res.write("123")
    await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
        .then((response) => {return response.json()})
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            res.write('456');
            res.end();
        });

}
```

seeing behavior: can see both 123 and 456 in the frontend.

I never use await and .then together before, not fully understand the difference. searching the web rn.

Comment: You need to use `res.end()` when you're done writing everything. See [difference between res.send and res.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692048/what-is-the-difference-between-res-send-and-res-write-in-express)

Comment: your first `.then` callback doesn't return anything, so `data` will be undefined.

Comment: Your second approach (`res.end()` after `fetch`) definitively won't work, because `res.end()` would be called *before* the fetch is finished ... Maybe if you show your actual code, and explain what you actually want to do, we could help you better. Because, I somehow assume, the result of this `fetch` should be part of the response to the client? If that's the case, you have to `await response.json()` because that's a promise as well ...

Comment: Why are you using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and not returning anything from your first `.then()` callback?

Comment: Furthermore you have to consider what happens, if `fetch` or `response.json()` throws an exception. THen none of your approaches will ever reach the `res.write("456")`

Comment: FYI, `fetch()` does not give you partial responses.    When you do `response.json()`, it waits for the entire response to be delivered before giving you anything.  So, you will have to `.end()` the response before `fetch()` will return anything.

Comment: Plus, something is funky here.  `res.write()` must be done to the `res` from an already existing request.  You can't then do a `fetch()` and somehow access that same request.  `fetch()` starts a NEW request that will need it's own `res.write()` and `res.end()` or just `res.send()` on the server.  I'd suggest you show a larger section of working code so we can see what's really going on here.  You can never do `res.write()` before a `fetch()` because before the `fetch()`, the `res` for that new request doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think `res` is just the usual Express `Response`. OP has the `fetch` response in `response`

Comment: @Phil - That's not very clear here.  This question is currently unclear and ambiguous and not a sufficient [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and needs a bunch of clarification. Regardless, that `res` would belong to some DIFFERENT request than the one that `fetch()` is about to create since the `res` that corresponds to that `fetch()` doesn't get created until AFTER `fetch()` is called.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP says `res` is [http.ServerResponse](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) and it appears to defined before the fetch request even begins given they said they can see the "123" in the response (to whatever this is)

Comment: @Phil - Yeah, so that `res` would have nothing at all to do with the `fetch()` that comes after it.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's right but it's still the same `res` in the `.then()` callbacks

Comment: With the update you've added, there is literally no difference to the handling of `res.write()`. The only difference would be how errors are handled in whatever calls `sendText()`; the first returns a promise that **always resolves** with `undefined`. The second returns a promise that may either resolve or reject

Comment: @Phil then how is it possible that adding the await before the fetch can make res.write() send 456? That's what I saw.

Comment: That entirely depends on what calls `sendText()` and how errors are handled

Comment: There is probably some additional code that calls `sendText()`. And in this code there might be something that causes a `res.end()` (either explicitly or implicitly). So when the `fetch` inside `sendText` is awaited it reaches the `res.end()` in there. If not, the "outside" `res.end()` is called before the `fetch` resolves, thus `res.write("456")` does not have any effect anymore (or even causes an error ...) However it may be, there are too many uncertainties in this question to be able to answer it ...

Comment: @derpirscher, thanks, I think your answer is the clearest and addresses my question directly. I used a nodeJS framework as backend, I didn't write additional code that calls ```sendText()```,  just used it inside of a normal controller. The framework, however, does something for me (I don't have control on this): as you said, there is probably something that implicitly calls ```res.end()``` before ```fetch``` resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't checking for any errors or an unsuccessful response so `response.json()` may be failing, preventing anything after it from executing.

Something like this should work better for you

```ts
async sendText (res: Response) {
  res.write("123");

  const response = await fetch("http://example.com/movies.json");

  // check for an unsuccessful response
  if (!response.ok) {
    const error = new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    error.text = await response.text();
    throw error;
  }

  const data = await response.json();
  res.write("456");
  res.end(); // finalise the HTTP response

  console.log(data); // log data for some reason ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
};
```

This will return a promise that **resolves** with `undefined` or **rejects** with either a networking error, HTTP error or JSON parsing error.

When calling it, you should [handle any rejections accordingly](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

```ts
app.get("/some/route", async (res, res, next) => {
  try {
    await sendText(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err, err.text);
    next(err); // or perhaps `res.status(500).send(err)`
  }
});
```

---

> I never use await and .then together before

Nor should you. It only leads to confusing code.