# FIREBASE WARNING Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I would use data stream to update automatically my angular material datatable when data get pushed to the database

Here's my router.js

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      var list = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
        list.push(elem.val());
      })


      res.send(list);

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
  });

router
  .route("/")
  .post(function (req, res, err) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.push(
      {
        "text": req.body.text
      }

    );

  });
```

When I run my app I get all my data, then when I try to post data to the database I get this error :

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

When I use `once` instead of `on` I don't get error, but as I need to fetch for new data every update on database, I should use  `on` to get a data stream.

So how can I use `on` without getting this error ?

Comment: .on binds an handler that doesn't go away. .once binds a handler that goes away. Clearly you want the latter solution that you've proven works.

Comment: A single request can't respond more than once, therefore listening for more than just the next change makes no sense.

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you can only send a response once.

Comment: once does not send an update to the front when new data is added

Comment: you can't do that with an http request.

Comment: So how can I create a stream of data ?

Answer (score 5):

When you attach a listener with `on("value")`, it will keep listening for the data. This means that it will also fire if the data changes later, at which point you've long sent a response to the client and closed the socket.

To prevent this, you should listen with `once("value")`:

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
      var list = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
        list.push(elem.val());
      })

      res.send(list);

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
    });
  });
```

I also added a response to the error handler.

**Update**

If you want to keep sending updates to the client, you'll want to keep the connection open. In that case you shouldn't call `res.send()` (which closes the connection), but `res.write()` (which leaves the connection open). See [Difference between response.send and response.write in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749590/difference-between-response-send-and-response-write-in-node-js)

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(function (req, res, err) {

    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.on("value", function (snapshot) {
      var list = [];
      snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
        list.push(elem.val());
      })


      res.write(list);

    }, function (errorObject) {
      console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
      res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
    });
  });
```

Comment: As I said that will not create a data stream . I mean in front end I have an observable that listen to my get http request. I would that when I post a data in database, my observable update the view automatically. With once it's not possible.

Comment: Calling `send()` closes the connection after the write. To keep the connection open, use `write()`. But in general for this type of approach, consider using Web Sockets instead of plain HTTP.

Comment: Now I get this error with write `FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer`

Comment: I guess that means you can only write `res.write(JSON.stringify(list))`